# An exercise to find the expectation of quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-evolution

Given $\vert\psi(0)\rangle=\vert 0 \rangle$,
$ H =\hbar\omega(\vert 0\rangle \langle 1 \vert+\vert 1\rangle \langle 0 \vert) $,
$p=\vert 0\rangle \langle 0\vert$,
ask for $\langle \psi(t)\vert p \vert \psi(t)\rangle$.
What should I do? I have no idea.

Comment: Oh my god!What I want to say is ask for $\langle \psi (t) \vert p \vert \psi (t) \rangle$

Comment: Your question is off-topic. Anyway, here is a hint: $H\sim \sigma_x$

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve Schrödinger's time-dependent equation
$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle = H|\psi(t)\rangle$$
for your given Hamiltonian and starting condition.

After having found the solution $|\psi(t)\rangle$ it is
straight-forward to calculate $\langle \psi(t)\vert p \vert \psi(t)\rangle$.

Comment: The Hamiltonian of this question does not contain a time factor and can be represented by $\vert 0 \rangle$ and $ \vert 1 \rangle $。Therefore, $\vert \psi(t) \rangle>$ expression is $\vert \psi(t) \rangle = e^{-iHt/\hbar} \vert \psi(0) \rangle=e^{-i\omega(\vert0\rangle\langle1\vert+\vert1\rangle\langle0\vert)t}\vert 0 \rangle$。Can I write as $\vert \psi(t) \rangle=e^{-iwt}\vert 0 \rangle $?

Comment: @ajowa No, you can't. Check if your $|\psi(t)\rangle$ satisfies the differential equation. It doesn't.